# Trying to save a photo with python, but when I execute the program with the terminal, It returns that there is no such directory

Tags: python, directory

I have been trying to execute this program:

```
 1 import PIL as pillow
 2 from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
 3 photo = Image.open("index.jpeg")
 4 b = photo.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
 5 b.save("/home/alex/spb/done","jpeg")
```

And I get a message saying:

```
 File "im0.01.py", line 5, in <module>
    b.save("/home/alex/spb/done","jpeg")
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1
966, in save
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/alex/spb/done'
```

How can I fix this?

Note: the program is in my working directory and the directory i'm saving to is also in there.

Comment: The error message (`Is a directory`) does not match the one in your title (*"there is no such directory"*) - it looks like you are trying to create a file with the same name as an existing directory

Comment: This question concerns python and is better off on StackOverflow.

Comment: Consider using the `{}` formatting tool so that it's easier to display the code as-is.

Comment: Problem resolved, had to enter file name after directory name.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Nasir Riley about moving this to stackoverflow, anyway I think that your issue is only because of the way you are using the save method, [according to the specs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.save) you have to provide the destination filename.

So you should try this:

```
import PIL as pillow    
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

photo = Image.open("index.jpeg")    
b = photo.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
b.save("/home/alex/spb/done/photo_blurred.jpeg")
```